# Why the output is different than the expected one?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I get the following output:

```
 i         101
 ii       10000
 ipart           3
 j         101
```

from the code:

```
program test
  implicit none

  integer ( 4 ), parameter :: Nx = 100, Ny = 100, npart = 2
  integer ( 4 ) :: ipart, i, j, ii
  real    ( 8 ) :: xx1,xx2,x1,y1,y2
  real    ( 8 ), dimension(Nx,Ny) :: eta
  real    ( 8 ), dimension(Nx,Ny,npart) :: etas

  do ipart = 1,npart
     do i=1,Nx
        do j=1,Ny
           eta(i,j) = 0.0
           etas(i,j,ipart) = 0.0
        end do
     end do
  end do


  !---


  x1 = Nx/2
  y1 = 40.0
  y2 = 70.0

  do i = 1, Nx
     do  j = 1, Ny

        ii = (i-1)*Nx+j

        xx1 = sqrt( (i-x1)**2 + (j-y1)**2 )
        xx2 = sqrt( (i-x1)**2 + (j-y2)**2 )


     end do
  end do
  
  print*, 'i', i
  print*, 'ii', ii
  print*, 'ipart', ipart
  print*, 'j', j
  
 end program test
```

I was expecting the following output

```
 i         100
 ii       10000
 ipart      2
 j         100
```

So why do I get different values of **i, ipart, and j**? I am using the command **gfortran main.f90** on Windows 10 gfortran compiler. How they can exceed the upper bound ?

Comment: The value of the loop iteration variable after the loop is the last value plus the loop step.